# The right way to save spinner to sharepreferences

Tags: android

I have a spinner that have 3 values populated from array-list.

I want to save the spinner selected value to shared preferences so it can be loaded back again when the use comes back to the app. What is the correct way to do this (to avoid future problems)

1- Save position of the selection

2- Save the text of the selection

3- Get the position/text of the selection, get the corresponding enum, and save the enum name.

I am leaning towards the 3rd option incase the positions/texts changed in later updates but I am wondering what is the correct way of doing such task

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save position (1 variant) and text (2 variant) are bad practice. Because text for your spinner items may will change in the future and their position can be changed.

I think, that you need to create enum or `@TypeDef` element and save it to sharedPreferences. `@TypeDef` is more performance but enum is more functionality (if you use Kotlin you can use `sealed` classes). For this solution just write mapper that can map enum to spinner item.

If you use enum, the best way is to save it name `ENUM.name()`.

Comment: Why would you save position if enum not its name? Because you might change enum positions in the code

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully and understand. Get the post and use at your own understanding.

Declare your spinner  and sharedPreferences

```
public Spinner crimeType;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesFirstTime;
//////



sharedPreferencesFirstTime = getPreferences
                (Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String firstTime = getResources().getString(R.string.saved_first_time);
firstTimekey = sharedPreferencesFirstTime.getString
(getString(R.string.saved_first_time),
                firstTime);


crimeType = v.findViewById(R.id.crimeType);
```

Initializing a String Array

```
    String[] plants = new String[]{
            "Antisocial behaviour",
            "Arson",
            "Burglary"

    };
```

Initializing an ArrayAdapter

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, plants
    );
```

Sets the layout resource to create the drop down views.

```
     /*

            Parameters : resource
                the layout resource defining the drop down views
     */

     spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
     (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Sets the Adapter used to provide the data which backs this

```
  /*
    setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter)
        Sets the Adapter used to provide the data which backs this Spinner.
 */
crimeType.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

crimeType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //Get the text content
        crime_string= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        //Get Position of the crime
        selectionPosition= 
              parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        String key2 = crime_string;
        editor.putString(getString(R.string.saved_login_key), key2);
        editor.apply();


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        //Another interface callback
    }
});
```

Comment: The only relevant part to my question is the last part and essentially you are going point 2 .what if you change array strings in next update of the app? Your pref are invalid

Comment: Yes it is.  You can use `enum` then. But that does not make this answer useless I believed